# Write String to a text file

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I have this code that gets GPS data from input stream make the test file but there is nothing inside. Can you please tell me what is the problem in here?

```
public void run ()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;
            try
            {
                while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
                {
                    String gpsInfo = new String(buffer,0,len);
                    PrintWriter data = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
                    data.println(gpsInfo);
                    System.out.print(gpsInfo);
                }
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
```

I am getting the right console output.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to call `data.close()`

Comment: still no luck on the output file. Do I need to append? Does the method overwrite the file every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are opening the same file repeatedly in the `while loop`**. You should open before going into the loop. Also `flush()` and `close()` the stream.

```
      PrintWriter data = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
      while((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        String gpsInfo = new String(buffer,0,len);
        data.println(gpsInfo);
        System.out.print(gpsInfo);
      }
      data.flush();
      data.close();
```

---

If you are using java 7 and above then you can open the file in try block itself. It will be closed automatically once your code in the try block completes. But don't forget to `flush()` the data.

```
  public void run () {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = -1;
    try (PrintWriter data = new PrintWriter("test.txt")) {
      while((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        String gpsInfo = new String(buffer,0,len);
        data.println(gpsInfo);
        System.out.print(gpsInfo);
      }
      data.flush();
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @MixAustria It is writing the output into file. I would suggest you to provide the absolute path of the file, for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The way you doing is actually correct. Once the data is written into a text file, **close** the `PrintWriter` instance.

```
data.close();
```

If you want to know about more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

**Code Snippet:**

```
PrintWriter data = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
String gpsInfo = null;

while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
{
     gpsInfo = new String(buffer,0,len);
     data.println(gpsInfo);
     System.out.print(gpsInfo);
}

data.close();
```

Comment: still no output on the text file.

Comment: tried the updated code but still no output on the  text file.

Comment: It works for me. `Provide the absolute path of the file` and try.